# Extracting and comparing only a certain column of a file

Tags: file, powershell

I need to write a PowerShell script, that allows the user to pass a txt file, that contains the standard information you'd get from a

```
Get-Process > proc.txt
```

statement as a parameter and then compare the processes in the file with the currently running ones. I then need to display Id, Name, Starting time and running time for every process, that isn't in the txt file and therefore a new process.

To give you a general idea of how I would approach this: I would

1. Extract only the names of the processes from the txt file into a variable (`v1`).
2. Save only the names of all the currently running processes in a variable (`v2`).
3. Compare the 2 variables(`v1`, `v2`) and write the processes that are not in the txt file (the new ones) into yet another variable (`v3`).
4. Get the process ID, the starting time and the running time for each process name in `v3` and output all of that (including name) into the console and in a new file.

First of all, how can I only read the names of the processes from the txt file? I tried to find it on the internet but had no luck.

Secondly how can I save only the new processes in a variable and not all the differences (e.g. processes that are in the file but currently not running).
As far as I know,

```
Compare-Object
```

returns all the differences.

Thirdly how can I get the remaining process information I want from all the process names in `v3`?

And finally how can I then neatly combine ID, starting time, running time and the names from `v3` in one file?

I'm pretty much a beginner at PowerShell programming, I'm pretty sure my 4 step approach posted above is most likely wrong and therefore appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: I thought you had actually read my answer to your previous question when you accepted it. The only step you need to take from there is filter by side indicator: `$v3 = Compare-Object ... -PassThru | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' }`. And to repeat myself (because apparently people never get it without me telling them twice), you don't want to parse the name out of a text file. Use a CSV or XML file as suggested in my answer.

Comment: As for your 3rd and 4th question: that should be covered in about every PowerShell tutorial on the planet.